# GraphQL query fragments on interface type implementations

Tags: graphql

Suppose I have two types, Comment and Query, that implement a common interface UserItem. I have a query that will return an array of UserItem objects that can be of either type, Comment or Query. The schema looks like:

```
enum ItemType {
  Comment
  Question
}

interface UserItem {
  id: ID!
  __typename: ItemType
}

type CommentContent {
  text: String!
}

type Comment implements UserItem {
  id: ID!
  __typename: ItemType
  content: CommentContent!
}

type QuestionContent {
  text: String!
  answer: String
}

type Question implements UserItem {
  id: ID!
  __typename: ItemType
  content: QuestionContent!
}

type Query {
  getUserItems(ids: [ID!]): [UserItem]
}

schema {
  query: Query
}
```

The query:

```
query getUserItems($ids: [ID!]) {
  getUserItems(ids: $ids) {
    id
    __typename
  }
}
```

works fine and returns both type objects with no `content` field in either.

The query:

```
query getUserItems($ids: [ID!]) {
  getUserItems(ids: $ids) {
    id
    __typename
    ... on Comment {
      content {
        text
      }
  }
}
```

works fine and returns `content` for Comment, but not Question. And the query:

```
query getUserItems($ids: [ID!]) {
  getUserItems(ids: $ids) {
    id
    __typename
    ... on Question {
      content {
        text
        answer
      }
  }
}
```

works fine and returns `content` for Question, but not Comment.

But what I want is the appropriate `content` field on each, something like:

```
query getUserItems($ids: [ID!]) {
  getUserItems(ids: $ids) {
    id
    __typename
    ... on Comment {
      content {
        text
      }
    }
    ... on Question {
      content {
        text
        answer
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This query is not valid, and returns an error message like (this from AWS AppSync): `Validation error of type FieldsConflict: content: they return differing types null and null`.

Is it possible to achieve my desire of getting object appropriate `context` for each type? Or is my schema approach doomed?

Comment: The query and schema look good to me. I tested in in launchpad and the server does not error https://launchpad.graphql.com/zr75vn4zz7 This seems to be a problem of AWS AppSync. Maybe you could address them directly with this problem.

Comment: @Herku Thx. I extended your launchpad slightly to verify that all works as I was hoping: https://launchpad.graphql.com/xnkq5nqj3l

I'll move my question to an AWS forum.